# UITableView crashing with no erros

Tags: crash, uitableview, nsurl

Basically, from the root of the navigation controller, a table view, I build a URL string that contains the information i want to display on the new tableView. in the new table view i use the URL for an NSURL request. My code gives me no error but crashes, right after the NSLog: made cells. help before i kill myself. sorry should all be together but copy pasting code obviously doesn't work well.

```
#import "CatDisplayViewController.h"
#import "CatViewController.h"


implementation CatDisplayViewController

@synthesize downvotebutton;
@synthesize upvotebutton;
//@synthesize tripsHold;
@synthesize URLtoUse;






NSArray *trips;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];



NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLtoUse];

NSLog(@"%@", url);

responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@" recieved response ");
[responseData setLength:0];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSLog(@" Did recieve data ");
[responseData appendData:data];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@" connection failed ");
NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

}

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];
NSLog(@" our connect finished loading");
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[responseData release];

NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

NSLog(@" released data ");
NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@" built JSON dictionary ");
NSArray *allTrips = [results objectForKey:@"results"];
NSLog(@" built array from dictionary ");

trips = allTrips;
NSLog(@" done with connectFinish method ");

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.

NSLog(@" in sections number ");

return 1;
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"%@", trips);
return [trips count];
```

}

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@" in height for row ");
return 80;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@" Trying to build table ");
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSLog(@"made cells");

NSDictionary *trip = [trips objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSLog(@" made dictionary from array ");

cell.textLabel.text = [trip objectForKey:@"txt"];
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [trip objectForKey:@"name"];

UIButton *upvote =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

UIImage *upVoteBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowup.png"];
[upvote setBackgroundImage:upVoteBack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[upvote setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
upvote.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 40.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f);
[upvote addTarget:self action:@selector(upvoteaction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:upvote];

UIButton *downvote =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIImage *downVoteBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowdown.png"];
[upvote setBackgroundImage:downVoteBack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[downvote setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
downvote.frame = CGRectMake(250.0f, 40.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f);
[downvote addTarget:self action:@selector(downvoteaction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:downvote];



//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[aTweet objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"]];
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

}

Comment: '_copy pasting code obviously doesn't work well_' - so edit it until it looks correct then - there's a preview window for a reason ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trips = [allTrips retain];
```

Your trips array is being autoreleased - try retaining it and see if you still get the error.

Comment: omg nevermind dont answer i had the wrong button type, should be custom. Thanks so much you are a god damn guru i literally posted that like 5 minutes before you responded.... almost feel like makin a note when we release it, THANKS TO DEAN WOMBOURNE (HE PROBLY SHOULD HAVE WROTE THIS WHOLE THING) =]

Comment: If you like my answer feel free to click on the grey tick on the left just under the voting buttons to give me some reputation . . . .  ;) Glad I could help.

Comment: well i will try, however, i don't have an account, do you mean the check mark? cause i clicked that, but one more thing, I just made a UI picker view and everything went smoothly, but do you have any idea how to disable the automatic picking when the scroll stops on a selection? my "boss" told me to "figure it out" cuase he wants it to click select, and i dont want to go try to make a stupid little tableview when this picker works so well.

Comment: As far as I know, the default behaviour of a picker is _not_ to pick automatically so it should already just work how your boss wants. But instead of asking me in the comments, ask it as a new quetsion (and post your code) - then everyone will be able to help you, not just me :) (PS The tick mark has appeared now, thanks!)